Evaluate $\,\int_{|z-\mathrm{e}|=2} \frac{1}{(z-1)\log z}dz$
evaluate $\int_{|z-e|=2} \frac{1}{(z-1)\log z}dz$
we know that $\log(z) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}(z-1)^n}{n}$
so $\int_{|z-e|=2} \frac{1}{(z-1)\log z}dz = \int_{|z-e|=2} \frac{1}{(z-1)(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}(z-1)^n}{n})}dz =  \int_{|z-e|=2} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{(-1)^{n-1}(z-1)^{n+1}}dz$
Is this how I should approach this question? If yes, I'm not sure what to do next.

Integrand has  a pole of order $2$ at $1$. Apply Residue Theorem.

The substitution $w=z-1$ helps. The result, $2i\pi\lim_{w\to0}\frac{d}{dw}\frac{w}{\ln(1+w)}$, is easily evaluated from the denominator's Taylor series.

The reciprocal of a sum is not the sum of the reciprocals! That is a serious mistake!

Here, $\mathrm{Log}\,z\,$ is the principal branch of the logarithm, defined in $\mathbb C\setminus\{x:x\le 0\}$, with $\mathrm{Log}\,1=0$. The function
$$
f(z)=\frac{z-1}{{\mathrm{Log}}\,z}
$$
is analytic in $\mathbb C\setminus\{x:x\le 0\}$, and
according to Cauchy integral formula:
$$\int_{|z-\mathrm{e}|=2} \frac{1}{(z-1){\mathrm{Log}}\,z}dz=\int_{|z-\mathrm{e}|=2} \frac{f(z)}{(z-1)^2}dz
=2\pi i f'(1)=\pi i,$$
since
$$
f'(z)=\frac{z\,\mathrm{Log}\,z-(z-1)}{z\,(\mathrm{Log}\,z)^2}
$$
and hence
$$
f'(1)=\lim_{z\to 1}f'(z)=\lim_{z\to 1}\frac{z\,\mathrm{Log}\,z-(z-1)}{z\,(\mathrm{Log}\,z)^2}=\lim_{w\to 0}\frac{(1+w)\,\mathrm{Log}\,(1+w)-w}{(1+w)\,(\mathrm{Log}\,(1+w))^2} \\ = \lim_{w\to 0}\frac{(1+w)(w-w^2/2+w^3/3+\cdots)-w}{(1+w)\,(w-w^2/2+w^3/3+\cdots)^2}=\lim_{w\to 0}\frac{w^2/2+O(w^3)}{w^2+O(w^3)}=\frac{1}{2}.
$$
